# Material has a missing parent with GUID. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity complains about the material with the following error:

```
[12:10:34] Material 'Fall_Main’ has a missing parent with GUID: dee7Scccab26a594689c449a6bfa2b04.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&).
```

What to do?

Comment: I think it means that material was based on a shader that is missing  (e.g. because its `.meta`  file was deleted/changed) .. if you find and select that material how does the Inspector look like?